# MongoDB: How to filter strings only containing specific characters?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a mongo database in which are all english words stored.
I want to get a collection of words which only contain specific characters.
e.g.: in database [ash, clash, bash, has]
asking for [ash] i want to get [has, ash] as an output.
perhaps there is a fast way, that i dont have to build some special datastructures.
i will code in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the .Net driver for mongo then its LINQ implementation should be straight forward to use. More on that here [MONGO LINQ](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver.html)Then it would be (some exceptions) just as targeting an ordinary IEnumerable.

Your problem is probably solvable using regex which could be used in a Where clause using linq. Regex have a tendency of being hard to debug so until you find the correct regex here is an alternative example (it can be further optimized).

```
private void Test()
    {
        // fetching from database
        // var samples = database.GetCollection<T>"collectionname").AsQueryable<Employee>();
        string[] samples = new[] {"nnn", "shhhh", "has", "s", "ash"};
        string chars = "ash";
        var matches = samples.Where(x => IsMatch(x, chars));
    }

    private bool IsMatch(string sample, string matchChars)
    {
        if (sample.Length != matchChars.Length)
            return false;

        sample = matchChars.Aggregate(sample, (current, c) => current.Replace(c, ' '));
        return sample.Trim().Length == 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a query... I am searching my ID where it contains 52C.

```
{ "_id": { $regex: '.*\Q52C\E.*', $options: 'i' } }
```

C# Equivalent:

```
await collection.Find(new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonDocument { { "$regex", $".*\Q{YourString}\E.*" },
                                                                 { "$options, "i" } })).ToListAsync();
```